# Loop through NSStrings in NSArray

Tags: iphone, ios, for-loop, nsstring, nsmutablearray

Basically what I want to do is this:
1. Grab .plist from URL
2. Put array from plist file into an NSMutableArray
3. Loop through each string in the NSMutableArray and sort them into multiple NSMutableArrays

I've already done 1 & 2 and I have an NSMutableArray good to go.
So this is what strings look like from the NSArray:

```
Looper|September 28th, 2012|http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4?TestLink|http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTM5NTkwMzI2MF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMTc5MjQ2Nw@@._V1._SY317_.jpg
```

This is a movie trailers app so what I want to be able to do is sort this string (and all other strings that are formatted similarly in the NSMutabeArray) into 4 different NSMutableArrays, and split them at the "|" using componentsSeperatedByString. This is what I have so far but when I log "titleArray" it only comes up with the first title in the array:

```
NSInteger count = [newTrailers count];
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    NSString* body = [newTrailers objectAtIndex:i];

    NSArray *splits = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:body, nil];

    NSMutableArray* titleArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray* descriptionArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray* linkArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray* posterArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (NSString* item in splits)
    {
        NSArray* parts = [item componentsSeparatedByString: @"|"];
        if ([parts count] == 4)
        {
            [titleArray addObject: [parts objectAtIndex: 0]];
            [descriptionArray addObject: [parts objectAtIndex: 1]];
            [linkArray addObject: [parts objectAtIndex: 2]];
            [posterArray addObject: [parts objectAtIndex: 3]];
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"Title Arrray: %@", titleArray);
}
```

Thanks for any help and I am new to for loops and ints, so please be easy on me!

Comment: Code looks fine, NSLog the count of the newTrailers array and post it here.

Comment: based on the string template you posted, the `parts count` should be 3 not 4...

Comment: If you mean to use titleArray (and others) outside the array, they need to be initialised outside the array. Otherwise you overwrite them in each loop iteration.

Comment: I'd recommend using an NSDictionary for each trailer, rather than an NSArray of each value

Comment: How is it a duplicate Owen? Completely different question. How do I not overwrite them, but keep adding new strings to the nsmutablearray, LordTwaroog?

Comment: @LordTwaroog looks like a noob copied your suggestion for an answer...

Comment: not sure if this related to your issue, but creating the `splits` array is irrelevant... its always contain one object, get rid of that extra step and just split the string directly into `parts`

Comment: Awesome KDaker! Post this as a question and I'll accept it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get rid of the `splits` array and its forin loop and just split the `body` string directly:

```
NSString* body = [newTrailers objectAtIndex:i];
NSMutableArray* titleArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray* descriptionArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray* linkArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray* posterArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSArray* parts = [body componentsSeparatedByString: @"|"];
if ([parts count] == 4) {

    [titleArray addObject: [parts objectAtIndex: 0]];
    [descriptionArray addObject: [parts objectAtIndex: 1]];
    [linkArray addObject: [parts objectAtIndex: 2]];
    [posterArray addObject: [parts objectAtIndex: 3]];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a sample code for iterating an array of string

```
NSArray *arr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"AString",@"AnotherString", nil];
for(NSString *str in arr){

    NSLog(@"%@",str);
}
```

in swift

```
let arr : NSMutableArray = ["A","B"]

for str in arr as! [String]
{

    print(str)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of array creation taking place in your code - especially, for each entry in the newTrailers array, you create arrays for the title, description, etc...

If I got you right, what you want to do should be done like this (not tested, simply your code a little rearranged):

```
NSInteger count = [newTrailers count];
NSMutableArray* titleArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray* descriptionArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray* linkArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray* posterArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    NSString* body = [newTrailers objectAtIndex:i];

    NSArray* parts = [body componentsSeparatedByString: @"|"];
    if ([parts count] == 4)
    {
        [titleArray addObject: [parts objectAtIndex: 0]];
        [descriptionArray addObject: [parts objectAtIndex: 1]];
        [linkArray addObject: [parts objectAtIndex: 2]];
        [posterArray addObject: [parts objectAtIndex: 3]];
    }
}
NSLog(@"Title Arrray: %@", titleArray);
```